# Notation for approximation of a distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, notation

Is there a standard well-known notation for approximation of a distribution?

If a random variable $X$ has exactly standard normal distribution then we write $X \sim \mathcal {N}(0,1)$.

But what symbol should we use instead of "$\sim$" when the real distribution is unknown and we know only its approximation?
For example, sample mean $\overline{X} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ has **approximately** normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \frac{\sigma^2}{n})$ when $n$ is large enough. I saw that some sources use symbol "$\approx$" in the following way: $\,\,\overline{X} \approx \mathcal{N}(\mu, \frac{\sigma^2}{n})$. But I'm not sure that symbol "$\approx$" is a standard well-known notation for approximation of a distribution.

Comment: I don't know what it means to say one distribution is approximately equal to another.  I can imagine several definitions in this context.  I'd say that you would need to define what you want precisely and introduce whatever notation you want to use in the context of that definition.

Comment: You can get an asymptotic definition of $\approx$ if you consider $\sqrt{n}(\overline{X}-\mu)$.

Comment: @J.G. And indeed saying $\sqrt{n}\left(\overline{X}  - \mu\right)\xrightarrow{d}\mathcal{N}\left(0,\sigma^2\right)$ amounts to the Central Limit Theorem

Comment: @lulu, First of all I am interested in approximation in the CLT context. CLT says that standardized sum of i.i.d r.v.s with finite variances converges in distribution to a standard normal r.v. But when we have only finite number of i.i.d r.v.s. (sample) then we can't use CLT directly. But in that case we can say that standardized sum of the r.v.s. has **approximately** standard normal distirbution if $n$ is large enough (usually for $n \ge 30$). I need notation which can highlight this.

Comment: @J.G. I know, but I don't need an asymptotic notation. I am interested in case when we have only finite number of i.i.d. r.v.s (finite sample) as I wrote in the previous post. I can write that $\sqrt{n}(\overline{X} - \mu) \approx \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ for $n \ge 30$. My problem is that I am not sure that symbol "≈" is a standard well-known notation for this.

Comment: How about $X \sim \left[\approx \mathcal{N}\left(0,1\right)\right]$ ?.

Comment: Not everything has to have a symbol. The English word 'approximately' with an other word or two of qualification or context would work nicely. But I have seen $\bar X \stackrel{aprx}{\sim} \mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma/\sqrt{n})$ and $\bar X \stackrel{\cdot}{\sim} \mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma/\sqrt{n}).$ Not saying I like them, and they are sufficiently rare that they should be explained at least once in the chapter, paper, report.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of stacking together two tildes, you could put a dot above and a dot below the tilde to indicate an approximate distribution(similar to a notation for approximate equal with a dot above and below an equal sign), as shown below:

$\overset{\lower{0.5ex}{\cdot}}{\underset{\raise{1ex}{\cdot}}{\sim}}$.